# How can I display an Android Screen on a computer monitor

Tags: display, android

I am using a mouse and keyboard with my Android phone, a Samsung Galaxy S3, but I want to use a monitor with it. Is there any way or any programs which allow me to display what is on the android screen on a monitor, or a laptop screen?

If you have any questions, please feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: There are many applications that do this. Please research a little—simply asking for program recommendations is not constructive as we don't want to generate a list of apps that do *XYZ*, sorry.

Comment: You might find some solutions at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of adapters to either directly connect your device (like this [one](http://www.mobilefun.co.uk/samsung-galaxy-s3-note-2-hdtv-adapter-tip-p35602.htm)) or wirelessly (like this [one](http://www.mobilefun.co.uk/samsung-galaxy-s3-wi-fi-display-allshare-cast-hub-ead-t10udegxeu-p35120.htm))

[image]

Comment: I believe thats an MHL adaptor isn't it? [This link from android.stackexchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24216/whats-wrong-with-the-mhl-connector-for-hdmi-output-on-the-samsung-galaxy-s3) may be of interest then